# How to write a nested map function

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I don't like dealing with tables. I would rather dealing with # and /@. So what is the best concise way of writing the following double table.

```
tbl = Table[{xi, ss[[vi]][[1]], ss[[vi]][[2]][xi]}, {vi, 
 Length[ss]}, {xi, 0, 1, 1/(Length[ss] - 1)}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

where a shorter representation of ss is :

```
ss={{0.1, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {0.6, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {1.1,InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {1.6,InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {2.1,InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {2.6, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {3.1, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {3.6,InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {4.1, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}, {4.6, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}};
```

Please note that the interpolation function is different at each row.

Thanks for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are literally gazillion ways to write this differently. One of them is to create your `xi` with `Subdivide`, create all tuples and apply a function that puts everything into order

```
{#2, #1[[1]], #1[[2]][#2]} & @@@ Tuples[{ss, Subdivide[Length[ss] - 1]}]
```

On the other hand your `Table` call isn't too bad. Note that you can directly iterate over your `ss` without using an index `vi`

```
Flatten[
  Table[{xi, vi[[1]], vi[[2]][xi]}, {vi, ss}, {xi, 0, 1, 1/(Length[ss] - 1)}],
 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not as nice as halirutan's `Tuples` but [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) could be useful here:

```
n = Length[ss];

Join @@ Array[{#2, ss[[#, 1]], ss[[#, 2]][#2]} &, {n, n}, {1, {0, 1}}]
```

This could also be written perhaps more appealingly as:

```
fn[n_][_[a_, b_]] := Array[{#, a, b[#]} &, n, {0, 1}]

Join @@ fn[Length @ ss] /@ ss
```